# Function to check if keyispressed

Tags: java, keyboard, mouseevent, keyevent, keystroke

I need to see if a modifier key is pressed(shift,ctrl,alt) for my mouse event(basically ctrl+click)

I was wondering if there is a simple function to check if a key is pressed without implementing a keylistner or action events so as to not have the hassle of keeping track of where the focus is or where the variables are.

Comment: I believe that is in the event already. Have you looked through the docs?

Comment: where in jsp, SWT, GWT, AWT, Swing ???, I was wondering too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the mask of which modifiers were pressed by calling [`InputEvent.getModifiers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiers%28%29).

Thus if you want to know whether a particular modifier was pressed (e.g. Shift), you could do this as

```
// (doesn't have to be a method, of course, you could easily do this inline)
private boolean wasShiftPressed(MouseEvent evt) {
    return evt.getModifiers() & InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK != 0;
}
```

Comment: So the mouse event itself has the modifiers? Perfect!

Comment: Yes (assuming you're using Swing/AWT) - only they're in an bitmask form, so all the modifier "flags" are combined as a single integer.  You can extract a single modifier as per the example above.